# Express homepage not rendered on server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am developing a react app that uses server-side rendering.
My routes work, except the homepage.  Not sure why.  I'm assuming I'm not setting up my express server correctly to handle the index route...?

The following is the module which handles express' setup and whatnot.  I'm assuming I have the `app.get('*)` or `app.use(express.static)` incorrect.

**app.js (server)**

```
require('ignore-styles')
const compression = require('compression')
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')

require('babel-register')({
    ignore: /\/(build|node_modules)\//,
    presets: ['env', 'react-app']
})

const universalLoader = require('./universal')

const app = express()

// Support Gzip
app.use(compression())

// Serve static assets
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build')))

// Always return the main index.html, so react-router render the route in the client
app.get('*', universalLoader)

module.exports = app
```

**universalLoader.js (server)**

```
import path from 'path'
import fs from 'fs'

import React from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
import { StaticRouter, matchPath } from 'react-router-dom'

import configureStore from '../src/store'
import App from '../src/components/App'

import routes from '../src/shared/routes'

import { getSiteInfo } from '../src/store/actions/siteInfo'
import { REACT_APP_SITE_KEY } from '../src/shared/vars'

import Helmet from 'react-helmet'

module.exports = function universalLoader(req, res, next) {

    // console.log('Loading....')

    const store = configureStore()
    const fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl
    let routeFound = false

    // Try to find a matched route
    const promises = routes.reduce((promise, route) => {
        var props = matchPath(req.url, route)

        // If route was matched, component exists, and has an initialAction
        // then call it's initialAction.
        // This action will most-likely load some data asyncronously
        if (props && route.component && route.component.initialAction) {
            promise.push(Promise.resolve(store.dispatch(route.component.initialAction(store, props))))
        }

        return promise
    }, [])

    // Load initial site data
    promises.push(Promise.resolve(store.dispatch(getSiteInfo(REACT_APP_SITE_KEY))))

    // Wait until all async data has been loaded
    Promise.all(promises)
    .then(() => {

        // Load index file path
        const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'index.html')

        // Read index file
        fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', (err, htmlData) => {

            if(err){
                console.error('read err', err)
                return res.status(404).end()
            }

            const preloadedState = store.getState()
            // console.log("PreloadedState:", preloadedState)

            const context = preloadedState
            // console.log(context)

            // Note: Pass in serverRequest prop so the App knows the domain it's on for meta tags
            const markup = renderToString(
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
                        <App serverRequest={req} serverResponse={res} />
                    </StaticRouter>
                </Provider>
            )

            const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic()

            // Somewhere a `<Redirect>` was rendered
            if(context.url){
                console.log('Redirected:', context.url)
                redirect(301, context.url)

            // we're good, send the response
            }else{

                // Page meta data
                const meta = helmet.title.toString() + helmet.meta.toString() + helmet.link.toString()

                // Prep state to be injected into DOM for client
                const pageState = `<script>window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(preloadedState).replace(/</g, '\\u003c')}</script>`

                // Inject state and markup
                const RenderedApp = htmlData
                    .replace('<script></script>', pageState) // Store state to pass to client
                    .replace('<meta name="helmet">', meta)   // Meta data
                    .replace('{{SSR}}', markup)              // Actual markup/component html

                console.log("SSR Rendered: ", req.path)

                res.send(RenderedApp)
            }
        })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("Error:", err)
    })
}
```

I am `console.log()`-ing when a route is being handled within `universalLoader()`.  All routes show in the console that stuff is happening.  Except my homepage.  It does not even show the "Loading..." message.

Comment: Please add the universalLoader code, as that's likely where your issue is.

Comment: Done.  My apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`express.static` will be serving up any files in your `build` directory. If it finds the requested file it will serve it up and end the request/response. No middleware registered after `express.static` will get the chance to run if a suitable file is found.

Based on this line:

```
const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'index.html')
```

it would appear that you have a file called `index.html` in your `build` directory. This will get served up by `express.static` when you hit the URL for `index.html` but it will also get served up if you just hit the `/` URL because `express.static` defaults to serving up `index.html`. See the `index` property here:

https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static

The directory you point `express.static` at needs to contain files that are **static**, i.e. that require no processing whatsoever. If any of the files need processing they need to live elsewhere. Note the parallels with how an Express app typically has a separate folder for `views`, which in many ways is similar to what you're trying to do.

I would also suggest commenting out `express.static` to see what effect that has. It should be a quick way to confirm that `express.static` is responsible for stopping your index route being reached.

**Update**

Based on your comments it would seem that you do have a static directory at `build/static` that contains your JS and CSS files. You can serve this up directly using:

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'static')))
```

However, this will cause all your URLs to change too, so `http://localhost/static/js/example.js` will now be `http://localhost/js/example.js`. To retain the original URLs you would need to put the `static` back in via the route path:

```
app.use('/static', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'static')))
```

Comment: Yes commenting out `app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build')))` does indeed allow my home route to process.  I'm not entirely sure what to do about it.  Inside the `build` folder is where all of the built files are placed, including the index.html page.

FWIW, I'm using create-react-app for this project.

Comment: @Gurnzbot I don't know what `create-react-app` does but typically you'd have a subfolder that is just for static files and serve up just that subfolder using `express.static`. Your `index.html` isn't static and shouldn't be in that folder. In theory you can put the `express.static` call near the end of your middleware chain so that it gets called after your other routes but you'd need to be very careful that none of those other routes does anything to get in the way.

Comment: `create-react-app` is FB's own boilerplate React project.  It hides all of the webpack stuff away from the user.  It's pretty neat and whatnot, but ejecting out of it is often the case when you want to get into in-depth stuff from what I've seen.  Anyways, the build process places index.html in the 'build' directory.  It also created a `build/static/` directory that has `js` and `css` static files.  I attempted to target that folder directly `app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'static')))` without any success.

Comment: @Gurnzbot Targeting that folder directly does sound like the right thing to do though you'd need to update all of the references to those files as they'll no longer have the `static` prefix on their URL paths. If you want to keep them in the same place you'd need `express.static('/static', path.resolve(...))` with the route path out front.

Comment: YES!  I had to use `app.use('/static', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'static')))`.  I also did the same for images I'm using that are not being imported into my components directly: `app.use('/images', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'images')))`.  If you update your answer above I will gladly accept it as correct :)

Comment: @Gurnzbot Done.